# Unknown behaviour of Java Program

Tags: java

```
    System.out.println(symbol_b.symbolName + "  " + symbol_b.pointsTo.size());

    // change the fieldpointsTo set of all above symbols
    for (int i = 0; i < samePointsTo.size(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < samePointsTo.elementAt(i).size(); j++) 
        {
            Symbol symbol = samePointsTo.elementAt(i).elementAt(j);
            System.out.println(symbol.symbolName);

            // if field information is already present
            if (symbol.fieldPointsTo.containsKey(fieldObj)) 
            {
                symbol.fieldPointsTo.get(fieldObj).clear();
                symbol.fieldPointsTo.get(fieldObj).addAll(symbol_b.pointsTo);
            } 
            else 
            {
                // we have to create field information
                symbol.fieldPointsTo.put(fieldObj, symbol_b.pointsTo);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(symbol_b.symbolName + "  " + symbol_b.pointsTo.size());
```

Before the *for* loop the size of **symbol_b.pointsTo** is *2*, but just after the *for loop* its value is changed from *2 to 0*. How it is happening can anyone tell me. I am not doing anything to symbol_b.pointsTo and symbol_b.pointsTo is a vetor.

Comment: What are the declared and/or run time types of these variables?

Comment: fieldPointsTo is a hashTable, pointsTo is a vector, and symbol,symbol_a, symbol_b is of type Symbol which is a user defined class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps pointsTo is not only referred to by that variable name, but is also a value returned by symbol.fieldPointsTo.get(fieldObj), so that when you call .clear() on that, it removes all the vector's elements?

Comment: I think this is the most likely explanation (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the case that:

```
if (symbol.fieldPointsTo.containsKey(fieldObj)) 
{
    symbol.fieldPointsTo.get(fieldObj).clear();
    symbol.fieldPointsTo.get(fieldObj).addAll(symbol_b.pointsTo);
}
```

the symbol variable points to `symbol_b`, `symbol_b` is not in the `fieldPointsTo` so it calls `clear()` on it?